# ¿Es posible añadir una fecha de vencimiento a las descargas de los productos digitales en Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Creé un sitio web para un gimnasio, está hecho en WordPress y WooCommerce y por temas de la pandemia, se vieron en la necesidad de ofrecer clases virtuales a los clientes.
Quisiera saber si es posible en Woocommerce, añadir una fecha de vencimiento para que los clientes puedan acceder a sus clases hasta una fecha límite. Ya que la parte de vencimiento que ofrece Woocommerce no es muy util porque es por días solamente.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Esta es una comunidad de programación, y por lo general no se da soporte de aplicaciones. Te invito a que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  y que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funcionamos.

Comment: fecha vencimiento - fecha actual ?

Comment: Fecha de vencimiento, es decir poder colocar una fecha en la que la descarga deje de estar disponible para el comprador.

Comment: si tu configuración sólo te permite poner días de validez sería cuestión de hacer la cuenta : fecha vencimiento deseada - ( menos ) fecha actual ( de compra ) en días y usar ese valor